# Large hexadecimal PRIMARY KEY - how to index substrings of the PK field?

Tags: mysql, index, referential-integrity, regular-expression, generated-columns

I have a requirement for a very large (in terms of the number of rows, not data) database, and need to use a very long, unique, hexadecimal `PRIMARY KEY` instead of the usual `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer.

As an example, lets say that the `PK` is similar to an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), say something like `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`.

So, apart from the usual searching by the `PK`, there will be a need to search by subfields of it - i.e. find all keys, that begin with "2001" (covered by the `PK`- should be [`sargeable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)), or (say) has `0db8` in their second set of four hex characters, and then to reference this 2nd key from other tables.

What is the best way to store such a primary key (assume that I am using MariaDB or MySQL)?

My thoughts are to do one of the following:

- one big column,
- have 8 columns and make a composite key,
- or something else.

From a general database point of view, what would be the best technical solution to server my requirements?

Apart from the purely technical aspects of the question above, I would also be interested in any recommendations that users here might have as to the best database engine to use in this case?

I will only have a couple more tables, that will have `FOREIGN KEY` references to the long hex `PRIMARY KEY`. I can do without the [`DRI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity#Declarative_referential_integrity) (Declarative Referential Integrity) if there are major performance benefits

Comment: PK is not a goal. You must think abot processing effectiveness primarily. *I will need to search by this field and, for example, find all keys, that begin with "2001", or has "0db8" in their second set of four hex characters* Does the searching task will be "one group, strict value" always?

Comment: @Akina there will be records with "random" key generated, and then there will be records, where key is "prefixed" (or suffixed, does not matter which end) with specific key, think of a telephone number, having area code added to it, but I need to find records with partial area code, or file path in system, and I need files stored in certain directory, or subdirectory. Come to think of it, the file path is the closest analogy. The search task will either be "match the path in this directory path" or "match the key having this subdirectory path". Does it make sense?

Comment: I do not see the problem. You may have a lot of natural partial columns, which are indexed safely for your searching, and you may have generated well-compacted column which is effective primary key. From the other side... can you predict what is "very large number of rows"? 1kkk? 1kkkk? Does natural key really makes sense? maybe AI PK of BIGINT will be more useful?

Comment: @Akina I have read other questions and I understand the bit of "does it make sense". This time, it what makes sense is to have as few columns as possible, that is why "subdirectory" is merged inside "identity". It is not important how many rows there will be, just that it has to support large quantity on not "die". It is experimental prototype, if/when it will reach 1kkkk entries, I will consider splitting whole thing in multiple tables probably. The question is more about columns.

Comment: *This time, it what makes sense is to have as few columns as possible* You have told that one of processing tasks is a filtering by a component. In this case the combining into single column will degrade the effectiveness dramatically (up to complete inoperability) while filtering subcomponent is not a prefix. Anycase the amount of columns is the most last reason which must be taken into account when you think about effectiveness.

Comment: @Akina okay, forgetting the need to do fancy searches inside this key, what about column data type and way to store?

Comment: *what about column data type* Depends on precise data format to store. For IPv6, for example, this is BINARY(32). For telephone number - BIGINT. For directory structure - VARCHAR. There is no general answer.

Comment: @Akina Of course, if any of those would be the case, I would choose any of mentioned simple formats. The question is about storing hexadecimal key and if you think that binary(32) would be format of your choice, please create it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Oops... sorry, for IPv6 according datatype is `BINARY(16)` (or VARBINARY(16) if IPv4/IPv6 addresses may be mixed). See [INET6_ATON() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Which version of MariaDB are you using? You should **always** include that in your questions!

Comment: Don't confuse presentation with a datatype. An IPv6 is 16 bytes of data, so you should use `binary(16)` as the datatype. You can always present it as an IPv6 address. Searching should be possible using bit operators -- even indexed.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - yes, you're right about the types - I was just interested in looking at the using substrings as FOREIGN KEYs aspect of the problem - if I was doing this again, I'd do stuff like [this](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-storing-ipv6/). I completely revised my answer today if you'd care to offer any feedback?

Comment: @Vérace Thank you for your commitment, I highly appreciate it. The ipv6 was just an example I gave to illustrate the kind of key I imagined, you going for `str:str:str:str:str:str:str:str` was the right idea. Your revised answer now fits even better to my initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<TL;DR>**

Regular expressions can be a very powerful tool for various data storage,  manipulation and indexing requirements - regexes' capabilities in conjunction with `GENERATED` columns can be even more flexible and powerful and provide a decent solution to the OP's issue.

In this particular case (rowing back from my initial answer!), MySQL or its derivatives are the only feasible solution. PostgreSQL doesn't allow `GENERATED` fields to be `FOREGIN KEY`s unless they're `UNIQUE`. Obviously, the requirement to be able to use small substrings as `FK`s can't be satisfied in this case, despite the fact that MySQL's regex implementation leaves a **lot** to be desired! PG could use `TRIGGER`s - but that's another question!

**</TL;DR>**

A relatively simple solution to your issue exists **if** (and maybe it's a big if), you have `PRIMARY KEY` string separated by the same character. A more complex solution is possible using regular expressions - both options are explored below.

You can use [`GENERATED`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column#MySQL)<sup>(*)</sup> columns (confusingly, these are also referred to as [`VIRTUAL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column) in the Wikipedia entry, which is also one of the storage classes for such fields - the other storage classes are [STORED | PERSISTENT]. From the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/):

- PERSISTENT (a.k.a. STORED): This type's value [i.e. data] is actually stored in the table.
- VIRTUAL: This type's value is not stored at all. Instead, the value [data] is generated dynamically when the table is queried. This type is the default.

<sup>(*) There are other terms for these columns, e.g. `COMPUTED BY` or `CALCULATED`</sup>.

MySQL's [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is (versions 5.7 and up):

```
col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expr)
  [VIRTUAL | STORED]  -- storage class 
  [NOT NULL | NULL]
  [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
  [COMMENT 'string']
```

In order to use such columns as `FOREIGN KEY`s, their storage class has to be `STORED`.

### "Simple" solution:

Your `PK` is of the format (a fiddle with the code and tests for this part is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea01000049951fe770ff5c4358be5db7)):

`str:str:str:str:str:str:str:str`  (str = 1-4 characters<sup>(*)</sup> - separated by colons)

<sup>(*) Not hex characters in this case - I messed around with MySQL's HEX() and UNHEX() functions to no avail. However, see discussion!</sup>

MySQL has an [IS_IPV6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-ipv6)() function, however, the MySQL 5.7 documentation also contains [this gem](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

- CHECK
  The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

So, I'm going to use MySQL 8 which has implemented them - if you want valid IP_V6 addresses in a version prior to 8, then you'll have to use a trigger. MariaDB has `CHECK` constraints from at least 10.3 onwards.

You mentioned that IPv6 was (only) an example - if any set of characters will do, then just remove the `CHECK` constraint - and see the complex solution below for a discussion on regular expressions.

I created this MySQL 8 table (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea01000049951fe770ff5c4358be5db7)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  ip_v6 VARCHAR (39) NOT NULL,
  host VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  
  ip_v6_token_1 VARCHAR (4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_v6, ':', 1), ':', -1))) STORED,
  ip_v6_token_2 VARCHAR (4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_v6, ':', 2), ':', -1))) STORED,
  
  INDEX (ip_v6_token_1),  -- required for FOREIGN KEYs
  INDEX (ip_v6_token_2),  --           "
  
  CONSTRAINT test_ip_v6_pk PRIMARY KEY (ip_v6),
  CONSTRAINT ip_v6_valid_ck CHECK (IS_IPV6(ip_v6))
);

-- do the same for tokens 3 - 7 as per requirements!
```

I inserted a few records and then:

```
SELECT 
  ip_v6_token_1 AS "Token 1",
  ip_v6_token_2 AS "Token 2",
  ip_v6         AS "IPv6:",
  host          AS "Host:"
FROM test ORDER BY host;
```

Result:

```
Token 1 Token 2 IPv6:                                    Host:
   2001    0db8 2001:0db8:0000:FFF0:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 host_1
     10       9 10:9:8:7:6:6:7:6                        host_2
   4001    1111 4001:1111:2222:FFF0:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 host_3
```

So far, so good - we have our tokens split out as required.

Now, we check the `FOREIGN KEY` support - create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_fk
(
  t_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

  --
  -- Other fields
  --

  token_1 VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
  token_2 VARCHAR (4),
  
  CONSTRAINT test_fk_test_ip_v6_token_1_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (token_1) 
      REFERENCES test (ip_v6_token_1) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  
  CONSTRAINT test_fk_test_ip_v6_token_2_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (token_2) 
      REFERENCES test (ip_v6_token_2) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

So, I tested the `ON DELETE CASCADE` and the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` functionality and they appear to work. Also, when one tries to `INSERT` on `test_fk` it fails if there isn't a corresponding token in the ip_v6 field of the `test` parent table - see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea01000049951fe770ff5c4358be5db7) for the tests.

### Complex solution (modelled on the above):

This part of the answer makes extensive use of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). I'm taking IPv6 as an exemplar of the power and flexibility of regexes - ultimately, you should be able to write your own in line with your particular requirements.

A fiddle for the code and tests can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84447d48ca64d2d94d01ef1b776dbbac).

As above, I `CREATE`d a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  ip_v6 VARCHAR (39) NOT NULL, 
  host VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,


  ip_v6_token_1 VARCHAR(39) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_v6, ':', 1), ':', -1)),
  ip_v6_token_2 VARCHAR(39) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_v6, ':', 2), ':', -1)),

  -- as in simple solution, same for tokens 3-7 as per requirements!

  INDEX (ip_v6_token_1),  -- required for FOREIGN KEYs
  INDEX (ip_v6_token_2),


  CONSTRAINT test_ip_v6_pk PRIMARY KEY (ip_v6),
  CONSTRAINT ip_v6_regexp_ck 
    CHECK(ip_v6 REGEXP '^([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7,7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}$')    
);
```

So, as you see, the change is on the `CHECK` constraint on the `ip_v6` field:

```
  CONSTRAINT ip_v6_regexp_ck 
    CHECK(ip_v6 REGEXP '^([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7,7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}$')
```

A brief explanation of the regular expression `'^([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7,7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}$'`:

- the `^` character is an `anchor` - it matches the beginning of a line.
  This ensures that the format of the ip_v6 string is (from the beginning) of 1-4 hex characters (of any combination) in the ranges of `0-9` **OR** `a-f` **OR** `A-F` - from [here](https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-os-x/regular-expression-reference.en#:%7E:text=An%20expression%20followed%20by%20%27*%27,times%2C%20but%20at%20least%20once.&text=When%20it%20is%20necessary%20to,Thus.) - groups of characters enclosed in `[` & `]` are called [`character classes`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). My regex above is equivalent to `'^([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$'`.
  From [here](https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-os-x/regular-expression-reference.en#:%7E:text=An%20expression%20followed%20by%20%27*%27,times%2C%20but%20at%20least%20once.&text=When%20it%20is%20necessary%20to,Thus.):

> When it is necessary to specify the minimum and maximum number of
> repeats explicitly, the bounds operator {} may be used. Thus. a{2} is
> the letter ‘a’ repeated exactly twice, a{2,4} represents the letter
> ‘a’ repeated between 2 and 4 times, and a{2,} represents the letter
> ‘a’ repeated at least twice with no upper limit. Note that there must
> be no whitespace inside the {}, and there is no upper limit on the
> values of the lower and upper bounds.

- the {1,4} [:xdigit:] characters are followed by a (character literal) `:` - it has no special meaning in regexps.
- the enclosing parentheses (`()`) (important for this discussion, see below) mean that the groups of hex digits concatenated with a single `:` are to be treated as a group - `"captured groups"` - see discussion re. MySQL vs. PostgreSQL!
- the {7,7} means 7 and no more nor no less than 7 repeats of that group can be present - since it ends with a colon, it **can't** be the last element. That is taken care of by the final group - `[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$` - where the usual 1 - 4 digit hex is followed by the `$` character.
- the `$` character is another `anchor`, this time signifying the end of the line - so the end of our `ip_v6` string must be the hex character(s) **without** a trailing `:`!

So, we've ensured that our `ip_v6` string at least corresponds to some of the basics about IPv6 addresses - now what can we do?

As can be seen, there are `INDEX`es (or `KEY`s - synonyms in MySQL) for the three token fields generated - so far so good. I don't have a realistic dataset to test, but if you do, you can see the effect of these indexes.

You can see that I've used [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) (esp. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992575/mysql-substring-extraction-using-delimiter)) - which is all well and good - but this will become more and more (totally) restrictive as your requirements become more complex! For some reason, the relatively easy [SUBSTRING()](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b96aa0351228fa7124ee3fc056ee192f) function is `"disallowed"` in `GENERATED` columns.

What you really need is the power of [`Regular expressions`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) - these are very powerful and come in handy in lots of scenarios - like the one in this question!

You will see in the fiddle that I have run a few tests - some of which work and some of which fail - as with the simple solution!

Actual regexps for IPv6 addresses can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses), [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/useful_regex.ipynb#Checking-for-IP-addresses). These are not for the faint-hearted - first link's example:

- (([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]).){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]).){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))

That's over 660 characters, and the second link's example is **1080** characters:

- ^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$

However, the `IS_IPV6()` function removes the need to use horrors like these!

Whether or which is correct/better is a bit above my pay-grade, but you can see from the discussion under the first link's answer (> 250 upvotes!) that it's a complex task to get right but also that regular expressions can be very powerful!

However, all is not rosy in the garden - if you look at my complex solution fiddle, I've added some regular expression tests and MySQL fails on a few - notably those using captured groups (that is, bracketing using `(` and `)`.

An example is this one (see the MySQL 8 complex [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8631aec673e6f546fe2588d020ceaeb4)):

It **SHOULD** work like this (see the last code snippet in the PostgreSQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8631aec673e6f546fe2588d020ceaeb4)):

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE
  (
    ip_v6, '(^[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}):([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}):([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}):(.*$)', '\4 xx \3   \2   \1'
  ) 
  AS "Rep text 2",
  ip_v6
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
Rep text 2                                      ip_v6
FFF0:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 xx 0000   0db8   2001  2001:0db8:0000:FFF0:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
123:123:123:123:123      xx  321    654    987  987:654:321:123:123:123:123:123
```

Notice the 5 last tokens of the `ip_v6` string followed by `xx` followed by tokens 3, 2 & 1 in that order - i.e. reversed as per the captured groups (`\3` &c.) in the `(`brackets`)`.

MySQL returns (fiddle - last snippet in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84447d48ca64d2d94d01ef1b776dbbac)):

```
Rep text 2      ip_v6
4 xx 3   2   1  123:123:123:123:123:123:123:123
4 xx 3   2   1  2001:0db8:0000:FFF0:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
```

MySQL simply treats the replacements for the captured groups (i.e. what would be the tokens) as string literals (4, 3, 2, 1) - this is quite simply **appalling** - instead of failing, it returns the **WRONG DATA**. MySQL does the same thing - incorrect data instead of failing for character class shortcuts - `\d` fails as a replacement for `[[:digit:]]` which works for [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8631aec673e6f546fe2588d020ceaeb4). **Again**, instead of failing, it returns an incorrect result!

In this PostgreSQL fiddle, I set up the `GENERATED` columns and my `FOREIGN KEY`s as per the MySQL complex solution fiddle - however, with PostgreSQL, there is a **total showstopper** for the OP's requirements.

There has to be a `UNIQUE` index (not just a simple one) on that column for it to be able to be used as an `FK`. Just for the sake of completeness, I did this, but it completely puts the kibosh on using PostgreSQL for this question's requirements - but hey, I learnt a lot going through all of this - I hope you have too!

Comment: Woah, this is very extended answer. Thank you - I did not even knew such thing as "virtual columns" were possible. I see your point regarding version information - to know if certain new features are available in the environment or not. I will take your suggestions in consideration, but I doubt I will implement such a complex solution in the production environment at the very beginning.

Comment: @Deele - you can start of with (relatively) simple regexes for your subfields and then as your requirements (and your abilities :-) ) grow, you can add more and more criteria to your expressions **and** maintain performance. I'll try and edit your question tomorrow to make it more suitable for here - it's been closed as a "shopping list" question - which I think is  a bit harsh - you've asked about very specific functionality and I gave you a technical justification as to why I think that PostgreSQL is the way to go. I'll change the question to just focus on the regexp part (not the best db!).

Comment: @Deele - there are some links on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look?

Comment: I'm fluent in regex, it was not the thing that scared me, but too many moving parts and dependencies, while I was going for something that could be working even on SQLite. While asking this question, I already started understanding issues about it and why is it good/bad. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Deele - From 3.31.0, SQLite supports [generated columns](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-generated-columns/) - can't find a fiddle for that! :-( Some stuff on SQLite regexes can be found [here](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/SQLite/functions/regexp).

Answer (score 1):

The data type you choose to store this key isn't going to make much of a difference for your performance. Rather, you should store the pieces of the key that you'll need to search on, in their own columns as well that way you can avoid **wildcard searches** (contains, ends-with, etc) which are inefficient and do **exact searches** instead. You can achieve this either from your application that's generating / managing the key or you can use a **generated persistent column** which you can read about [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/). Either way, by breaking out the pieces of the key you'll end up doing **exact match** searches on allows you to index those pieces efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth considering `FULLTEXT` index in MySQL. For example,  these table definitions are allowed in MySQL 5.7:

```
CREATE TABLE `nested_obj` (
  `id` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `obj_id` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY (`obj_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_obj_id` (`obj_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`obj_id`) REFERENCES `nested_obj` (`id`)
);
```

Then you can do non-joined searches in `event` table using `match(obj_id) against('word')` predicates, it understands colon as word delimiter. You may additionally use regexp predicate to set the position of a searched word, like:

```
select obj_id, count(*) from event
where match(obj_id) against('sixfour')
and match(obj_id) against('fiveeight')
and obj_id regexp '^([^:]+:){1}sixfour'
group by 1;
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| obj_id                                                 | count(*) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ninesevennine:sixfour:fiveeight:fourfour               |        2 |
| threeeight:sixfour:twonine:fiveeight                   |        5 |
| threefivefive:sixfour:fiveeight:sevenfivesix           |        1 |
| zerofournine:sixfour:sevenzerotwo:sevenseven:fiveeight |        8 |
+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+

select obj_id, count(*) from event
where match(obj_id) against('sixfour')
and match(obj_id) against('fiveeight')
and obj_id regexp '^([^:]+:){2}sixfour'
group by 1;
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+
| obj_id                                              | count(*) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+
| fiveeight:oneone:sixfour:fourfiveeight:sixzero      |        6 |
| fiveeight:threefiveseven:sixfour:zerozerofive       |        7 |
| zerosixthree:sevensix:sixfour:fiveeight:onezerofive |        4 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

But the performance benefits of this solution are unclear. I guess it will highly depend on the particular distributions of values in the dataset.